# Data loss in Django - SQLite

Tags: django, sqlite

The stack I'm using: Ubuntu 64bit - Django (1.4) - SQLite (can't remember I installed this one but I think it ships with either Ubuntu or Django) - uwsgi (1.2.3 the server) - Nginx(1.1.19) - Extjs (4.1)

I've been using Django for approximately 2 months now and over the last 40 days or so, on three different occasions, I find that ALL tables in my SQLite database are empty (I could write truncated but I don't know the reason).

It is work in progress so I reshape the models (occasionally) and run manage.py syncdb (maybe once a day) but as I've read syncdb doesn't truncate or delete any table. I have to restart the uwsgi server a lot (every other statement) since it caches the application.

I'm mostly concentrating on the client part so the database is awfully simple with only a few tables and zero relations so far.

Anyone else experiencing this misbehavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start using South http://south.aeracode.org/

Comment: Apart from the fact that South may be useful, has it any correlation with the data loss I'm experiencing that you know?

Comment: Syncdb does not handle ANY changes you make to your models, data loss seems a pretty logic result, you're doing it wrong

Comment: Django documentation:
Part I:
Syncdb will not alter existing tables syncdb will only create tables for models which have not yet been installed. It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes made to a model class after installation. Changes to model classes and database schemas often involve some form of ambiguity and, in those cases, Django would have to guess at the correct changes to make. There is a risk that critical data would be lost in the process.

Comment: Part II: If you have made changes to a model and wish to alter the database tables to match, use the sql command to display the new SQL structure and compare that to your existing table schema to work out the changes.

Comment: Jup every change you make to your model will require you to create a script to migrate your data, which is very impractical, thats where south comes in to make your life easy :-)

Comment: IMHO data loss is not 'pretty logic' so I'll await another answer

Comment: I have no idea how you'd expect a simple command like syncdb to be able to migrate your data after you've changed model names, properties and/or fields, again, you should have a look at south.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13986/discussion-between-paul-and-argskwargs)

Comment: I got'm It's ... Eclipse sometimes I hit F11 by accident and that runs a python unit test. That unit test crashes horrible against my Django project. And wipes the content of the database completely. Thanks again.